# Which Polaroid Camera has been used here?

Tags: film, polaroid, camera-identification

Can you guys help me out identifying the Polaroid model used in the following videos?

- [First Video](http://youtu.be/KCHkYLM6pNQ?t=4m2s) -- screenshot:

[image]

- [Second Video](http://youtu.be/NEZFCz9lZ7Y) -- screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a Polaroid Spectra Pro to me. Here are some Google images of that camera [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=spectra%20pro%20polaroid&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS512US512&espv=210&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=aK7UUt3ODoSL2wW_1oDoCg&ved=0CDIQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=954#q=polaroid%20spectra%20pro&tbm=isch).

Here is a bit of historical information on the Spectra and Spectra Pro: http://camerapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Polaroid_Spectra#Spectra_Pro

Comment: Note that model was named `Image` (and there was `Image 2` as well which is the equivalent of the `Spectra 2`) outside the US. And yes, I agree with you this is the model which match the best with the one in the videos.